# Troca de informações direta entre Android e Desktop

Tags: java, android, cliente-servidor, aplicação-desktop

Pessoal eu gostaria de saber se é possível eu desenvolver um app que se comunique diretamente com um outro aplicativo que eu desenvolvi no computador, sem a necessidade de um servidor ou webService para a troca de informações. Se possível dicas por favor.

Comment: Socket?! bluetooth?! Wi-fi?! Telepatia?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para a comunicação de um aplicativo do dispositivo A para um aplicativo do dispositivo B é necessário que exista alguma rede ou conexão que ligue ambos dispositivos seja ela a Internet, Bluetooh, WiFi, conexões via cabos entre outros. Mas como você disse que não que não queria usar Web Service ou Servidor será necessário, usar uma das funcionalidade com fio, Bluetooh ou WiFi. Por isso recomendo que use um  Servidor para isso, já que desktops não possuem WiFi e os laptops mais antigos também não contam com essa funcionalidade. Já bluetooh nem vou citar já que são poucos os laptops que tem a funcionalidade bluetooh integrada e os quem tem vamos dizer assim não são convencionais para a maior parte da população. Desculpe se a resposta está incompleta ou não está como o desejado, para min sua pergunta carece de algumas informações especifícas